# Python 3 - How to split every character in a string into a list while keeping decimal numbers intact?

Tags: python, list, split, stack, calculator

```
string1 = '1+2*3/4'
string2 = '1 +2* 3 /  4'
string3 = '1.2*2+3/4'

string1List = list(string1)
string2List = list(string2)
string3List = list(string3)
```

I need to split any string I'm given into a list, and I need to break it up by character since there will be random spaces put into the inputted strings like string2 in my code example.

I get my desired outputs with string1 and string2:

```
string1List = ['1', '+' , '2' , '*' , '3' , '/' , '4' ]
string2List = ['1', ' ' ,' +' , '2' , '*' , ' ' , '3' , ' ' , '/' , ' ' , '4']
```

but string3 is not working the way I need it to:

```
# Actual result
string3List = ['1', '.' , '2' , '*' , '2' , '+' , '3' , '/' , '4']

# What I need as a result
string3List = ['1.2', '*' , '2' , '+' , '3' , '/' , '4']
```

Is there any way which doesn't utilize imports to continue splitting strings by character while preserving floats?

Comment: Why do you not want to import anything?

Comment: For homework you should put more effort in your question, you have try nothing yet.

Comment: @FlorianBernard my post was just meant to be an example of how it should work, not my actual code. (to avoid cheating infractions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` with an alternation:

```
string3 = '1.2*2+3/4'
parts = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[+*/-]', string3)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['1.2', '*', '2', '+', '3', '/', '4']
```

In other languages, we could have tried to do a regex split on lookarounds.  But Python's `re.split` does not support splitting on zero width lookarounds, so `re.findall` is one workaround.

Comment: except for some reason, they don't want to import `re`

Comment: @randomfigure Then the OP is going to have to write a parser.  Not the hardest thing to do, but might a bit broad for a single SO question.

Comment: Why you want to workaround split ? Why not `parts = re.split(r'([+*/-])', string3)` What a diff?

Comment: @splash58 Your suggested regex split would _consume_ the various arithmetic operators.  The OP wants to retain those, too.

Comment: @randomfigure This is for a class assignment, so I'm not allowed to use imports

Comment: This is result of my code - `['1.2 ', '*', '2', '+', '3', '/', '4']` You can try it

Answer (score 1):

One pass custom split by arithmetic operations  :)

```
string = '1.2*2+3/4'

s = 0
res = []
for i in range(len(string)) :
  if string[i] in '+*-/': 
     res.extend([string[s:i], string[i]])
     s = i+1
res.append(string[s:])
print(res) # ['1.2', '*', '2', '+', '3', '/', '4']
```

Comment: for some reason, the accepted answer includes imports, but the question explicitly states they don't want imports